# UIViewController, UITableView, Protocol

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UIViewController`, which has a

```
 @interface MYViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate>

  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
```

Now I am implementing the UITableViewDelegate because I want to use the tableview.

so in my `viewdidload` I do

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
   [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tblView.delegate = self;
    //self.tblView.dataSource = self;
  }
```

Now the `Datasource` setting throws a warning, and I never hit the

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

method.

Sorry about the editing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your problem?question should be clear.

Comment: tblView property should be strong not weak.

Comment: @Andraw that depends, if its the parent view it shouldn't be, if its a child view of a main view it should be (best practice) so releasing the main view releases everything else.

Comment: in this case its not the parent but a child, should I make it strong?

Comment: @funkycoldmedia: nope..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need

```
self.tblView.datasource = self;
```

also adopt to `UITableViewDatasource` Protocol,

```
@interface MYViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDatasource>
```

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is a datasource method.

Answer (score 0):

Your interface should also implement the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

```
@interface MYViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> 
{ 
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below..
UIViewController.h

```
@interface MYViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
  @property (Strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
```

please don't forget to connect tblView outlet to tableView in your .xib file, since this is very required otherwise your datasource methods won't get called.

In UIViewController.m file

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {  [super viewDidLoad];
self.tblView.delegate = self;
self.tblView.dataSource = self; }
```

and implement two required datasource methods

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{ return (number of row you want in table)}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ return cell }
```

surely this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

For UITableViewDatasource Protocol add `UITableViewDatasource` to

```
@interface MYViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource>
```

and add this line to `viewDidLoad`

```
self.tblView.datasource = self;
```

and go to your storyboard and link 'datasource' and 'delegate' to your `tblView`

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems in your implementation.

1. You are not conforming to UITableViewDatasource protocol.
2. You are not setting tableview datasource.
3. You are not implementing UITableViewDatasource protocol's required methods

You cannot expect to work without setting datasource.